# How to package apk with external library to android mobile

Tags: java, android

I have added the external library using eclipse. Everything is fine in the emulator. However, when I tried to install the apk file in real android mobile, it cannot be installed.
Actually, I followed this steps to add external library.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary

Hope someone can help. Thank You.

Comment: Why the apk cannot be installed. What is the error message in the console or logcat.

Comment: I used eclipse to export an unsigned APK. However, the APK cannot be installed in the mobile. The file size of APK is smaller than the external jars that i added. Is that mean the jars is not included in the apk? Sorry, i am a beginner.

Comment: From Eclipse, in your main project, create the signed apk (by rightclicking on project -> Android Tools -> Export signed application package) and fill in the information in the pop up dialog. Now load it in an emulator copy the apk in <android-home>/platform-tools folder and run "adb -e install <apk-name>". This way you will see if your apk, generated through eclipse, can run in emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the option set in your phone to accept installs from unofficial sources?

Comment: Yes, I think I cannot include the external library in the apk file.
In the emulator the apk is 1.8mb. The apk file i generated is 365KB.

Comment: I have both AdMob and GoogleAnalytics libraries packaged with my application.